# Array of objects with same key and different values using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to display `aliasName` based on array of objects?

```js
var test = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DEPT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How to display the alias names in input field based on table name using test. array?

Comment: Will the table row always the same order with the array?

Comment: No,It will not be same order.It will be changed depends upon the data

Comment: So, how will we know which goes which? You have multiple `EMP`.

Comment: @Eddie I think he wants the entire table to be created dynamically with the array.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict duplicate values into input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and use its index to help you get the specific element of array that you need.

```js
var arr = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];
           
$("tbody tr").each(function(index){
  console.log(index + " : " + arr[index].aliasName);
  $(this).find("input").val(arr[index].aliasName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DEPT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Or, if you want to search dynamically, you need to search and remove the value that you're using to prevent duplication.
You can use [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search and [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove.

```js
var arr = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];
           
$("tbody tr").each(function(index){
  let td = $(this).find("td").text();
  let obj = arr.find(x => x.tableName === td);
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 1);
  $(this).find("input").val(obj.aliasName);
});

console.log("Array after example with .splice() have " + arr.length + " elements.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DEPT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Or you can add a flag to the object:

```js
var arr = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];
           
$("tbody tr").each(function(index){
  let td = $(this).find("td").text();
  let obj = arr.find(x => x.tableName === td && !x.used);
  if(obj !== undefined){
    obj.used = true;
    $(this).find("input").val(obj.aliasName);
  }
});

console.log("Array after example with flag have " + arr.length + " elements.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DEPT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'used' of undefined

Comment: It will only happen if you have an array bigger than the number of `<td>`. Edited the answer, just check if it's different than `undefined`. :)

Comment: You can check in [Microsoft Docs about splice Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/splice-method-array-javascript). :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve selecting all your inputs inside your table and setting it with the foreach method,

```js
var test = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];
           
 var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('tbody input');          
 
test.forEach(function(element,index){
  inputs[index].value = element.aliasName;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>DEPT</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>EMP</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

anyways you can be more precise if you use some Id or class for each input...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery for this. You can easily generate the entire table in JavaScript like this:

```js
var test = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];

var html = '<table><thead><td>Table Name</td><td>Alias Name</td></thead><tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td>' + test[i].tableName + '</td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" value="' + test[i].aliasName + '" data-table="t4" maxlength="30" /></td>'
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</tbody></table>';

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: without javascript.I need it in jquery

Comment: Then change the last line to `$("#test").html(html);`. I don't know what difference that makes to you, be there you have it.

Comment: In my case table is showing.After i want to replace the value with aliasname

Comment: That's not reliably possible if the data change. See the other answers for that, but it is guaranteed to break when the data change.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery that will solve the issue

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var test = [{tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E1"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:"E2"},
            {tableName:"DEPT", aliasName:"D"},
            {tableName:"EMP", aliasName:""},
           ];           
test.forEach(function(item){
  $("tbody").append('<tr>'+
      "<td>"+item.tableName+"</td>"+
      '<td><input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30" value="'+item.aliasName+'"/></td>'+
      '</tr>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <td>Table Name</td>
  <td>Alias Name</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Arrow of functions is not working.How to fix this issue

Comment: which arrow function? Did you mean array of function?

Comment: give a `$( document ).ready(function() {});`  I updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create entries dynamically which is more reliable in your case.

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Table Name</td>
        <td>Alias Name</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    var test = [{ tableName: "EMP", aliasName: "E1" },
    { tableName: "EMP", aliasName: "E2" },
    { tableName: "DEPT", aliasName: "D" },
    { tableName: "EMP", aliasName: "" },
    ];
    let tbody = $('tbody');
    let html;
    for (let { tableName: name, aliasName: alias } of test) {
        html += `<tr>
            <td>${name}</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="alias" name="alias" data-table="t4" maxlength="30" value="${alias}">
            </td>
            </tr>`;
    }
    tbody.html(html)
</script>
```

Comment: In my case table is showing.After i want to replace the value with aliasname

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get you.

Comment: My issue is fixed.